# wildfly cli | write-attribute does not work

Tags: java, ms-access, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to update the mdb-delivery-group active value in the wildfly cli.

Reading with this command is working:

```
./subsystem=ejb3/mdb-delivery-group=<group>:read-attribute(name=active)
```

it returns:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => true
}
```

When I try to write the attribute with this command:

```
./subsystem=ejb3/mdb-delivery-group=<group>:write-attribute(name=active,value=false)
```

it returns:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYCTL0484: A
ttribute definition of attribute 'active' is null",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

The wildfly server logs tells me the same:

```
12:44:02,437 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("write-attribute") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
        ("mdb-delivery-group" => "<group>")
    ]): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYCTL0484: Attribute definition of attribute 'active' is null
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractWriteAttributeHandler.getAttributeDefinition(AbstractWriteAttributeHandler.java:259)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractWriteAttributeHandler.execute(AbstractWriteAttributeHandler.java:88)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.operations.global.WriteAttributeHandler.doExecuteInternal(WriteAttributeHandler.java:208)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.operations.global.WriteAttributeHandler.execute(WriteAttributeHandler.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1045)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:777)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:448)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$executeForResponse$0(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:304)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeForResponse(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeOperation(ModelControllerImpl.java:253)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:236)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:241)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$400(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:328)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:285)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

We recently upgraded our wildfly version from wildfly-21.0.2.Final to wildfly-25.0.1.Final. On version 21 it was working with those commands.

Can somebody help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should fill a Jira for this on https://issue.redhat.com . The fix is simple